# AS3 SharedObject IF isset or equals

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cookies, actionscript, shared-objects

very new to SharedObjects, but essentially all I want to do is let a user answer a question once and not allow them to answer again, how is it possible. This is what I have below?

```
/*if(_question.data.seenQuestion == "true") {
    cookie_txt.text = "COOKIE FOUND";
} else {
    cookie_txt.text = "NO COOKIES";
}*/


var _question:SharedObject;
_question.data.seenQuestion = "true";
_question.flush();
_question.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're very close. It looks like you're not actually creating a `SharedObject`, to do that you would use the method `getLocal`:

```
var _question:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("questionData");
```

Additionally, since `SharedObject` supports primitive types (`String`, `int`, `Number`, `Object`, `Boolean`, etc), you should store a `Boolean` instead of a `String`:

```
if(_question.data.seenQuestion)
{
    cookie_txt.text = "COOKIE FOUND";
}
else
{
    cookie_txt.text = "NO COOKIES";
}

_question.data.seenQuestion = true;
_question.flush();
```

Lastly, if you're using a local shared object (more common), you don't need to call `close()`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! How are you with URLRequest/GET (from PHP file?)

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as correct. What help do you need with `URLRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create your SharedOBject or else your code will throw errors:

```
var _question:SharedObject = SharedOBject.getLocal("myapp");
```

No need for flush or close just assign/change some data and that's it.

```
_question.data.seenQuestion = "true";
```

However SharedObject is not a good solution for persistent data. User can erase it/reset it, etc ...

Comment: You didn't remark the following error: `_question.data.seenQuestion = "true";`. So your answer is uncomplete (voted down).